# Profile error on existing Contribution Page

Tags: civicontribute, profile

We have an existing contribution page that had two profiles included (one for top of page, one for bottom). I'm not sure when this broke, but currently (v 5.10.3), the bottom profile now appears to NOT be selected, and when you first click on the "profiles" tab, you briefly see the following warning:

> The selected profile is using a custom field which is not assigned to
>   the "Membership" being configured.

The profile doesn't appear in the dropdown at all. I can see the fields if I preview or edit from this screen. If I choose another profile and save, the error does not show again, but the profile I need does not appear in the list, so I have no way of selecting it.

I'm not sure what this error means. How do you assign a custom field to a membership?

I have seen some posts here with similar-sounding errors, but they all seem to be related to issues that have long since been fixed.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the Profile that you are using has a field in use that may be a field that is set to only function for certain Membership Types, and that the Contribution page that you are showing it on does not offer that Membership Type.

I suggest you

- go to Admin > Customise > Profiles and find the Profile in question
- examine the fields in use on that Profile
- go to Admin > Customise > Custom Fields and find the Field set that contains the field(s) in question
- examine the Field set (via Edit) and see what entities eg Memberships it is set to operate with

Comment: Thanks for the information!  You are right -- it is apparently due to the custom fields in the profile being those for organizations, not memberships. But I am really confused!  1) This used to work - we were able to choose this profile and use it when the page was set up. Any idea when or why this changed? 2) Why the limitation? It looks like I can have contact fields in the profile, just not custom fields that don't relate to membership. I don't understand the logic.

Comment: Here's an example of my not understanding the logic: This is a Contribution page for a Business membership. We would like certain info about the business: logo, industry, etc. These custom fields seem to me like they relate to the organization entity, not the membership entity. However, if I understand correctly, the only way to get this info populated is to relate it to the org's membership, not the org itself?

Comment: Are we talking about the Profile for the On Behalf Org, or the standard type of  profile on a Contribution page. If the latter then i suspect it isn't working if you have Org custom fields, as the page would be expecting this to be submitted by an Individual. Does it work to move your Org fields on to the 'On Behalf of Org' profile?